# How to use more than 20 nested for loops in python3 program without any exception of too many statically nested blocks?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am upto creating a lookup table for a Human modelling software, Makehuman I have to translate its scale into real world metric scale for that I am creating lookup tables. It has 25 parameters that needs to be varied, I am using nested for loops for that and store values finally in database SQlite .  Please anyone tell me how can I modify my code or use some other technique to overcome this exception, because this has to run anyhow for the completion of my project.

Thank You.

Comment: What exception are you getting? You should probably try to get some of that code into functions.

Comment: @mypetlion thats cool, i made a function of some part of the loop and it works now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itertools` module over loops...

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html